# How to get CSS animated background image which is currently displaying using java script

Tags: javascript, animation, css-animations, addeventlistener

Currently i am running CSS based `ken burn effect` using opensource code  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VzYRWV

I would like to know how to get the current image which is getting displayed in text box shown in the above demo.

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks.. I will try and update

Answer (score 0):

**Try these CSS effects** https://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/cugLbrfu/4/

```
.parent.rotate:hover .child, .parent.rotate:focus .child {
    -ms-transform: rotate(7deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.parent.scalein:hover .child, .parent.scalein:focus .child {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.parent.scaleout:hover .child, .parent.scaleout:focus .child {
    -ms-transform: scale(0.9);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
    -o-transform: scale(0.9);
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

Created two new scale In and Scale Out

Source

https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can catch [css-animations](/questions/tagged/css-animations) events with javascript function [addeventlistener](/questions/tagged/addeventlistener)

Ex.

```
// first image
var img = document.getElementsByClassName('slideshow-image')[0];

// fired on animation start
img.addEventListener("animationstart",function() {
    // do stuff here
    console.log("Animation start");
},0);
```

> Now, although this works well and how it is supposed to do it, with *(not your)* example will not work well since the animation is not sequential but all at the same time. (Controls the percentage instead of "steps")

But, you can get the idea and play with it to archive what you're looking for.

**Important note**: Vendor prefix is still used.

Additional references:

- [Event reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events)

  - [animationstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationstart) *A CSS animation has started.*
  - [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) *A CSS animation has completed*
  - [animationiteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationiteration) *A CSS animation is repeated.*
  - [transitionstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionstart) *A CSS transition has actually started (fired after any delay).*
  - [transitioncancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitioncancel) *A CSS transition has been cancelled.*
  - [transitionend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) *A CSS transition has completed.*
  - [transitionrun](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/transitionrun) *A CSS transition has began running (fired before any delay starts).*
- [Detecting CSS Animation Completion with JavaScript](https://davidwalsh.name/css-animation-callback)
- [CSS Animation Events](http://callmenick.com/_development/css-animation-events/)
- [SO tag addeventlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/addeventlistener)
- [SO tag css animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-animations)